# How can i show a control depending upon value in a list using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list retuned from MVC controller to angular controller as follows:

result.data.mylist = (<Test1, true>,<Test2, false>,<Test3, true>)

```
I have 3 controls*textboxes)  that always sit on a form , TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3.
```

I want to only show the textbox where the value is true.
So in the above , since Test1 = true (TextBox1 is visible) and TextBox3 is visible since Test3 is true.
I can do it if it was a simple binding but how do i even start this in AngularJS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular's built-in `*ngIf` directive.

For example,

```html
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="result.data.mylist[0]">
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="result.data.mylist[1]">
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="result.data.mylist[2]">
```

Assuming that `result.data.mylist` is an array containing boolean values.

Alternatively, you could disable them using,

```html
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="result.data.mylist[0]">
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="result.data.mylist[1]">
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="result.data.mylist[2]">
```